# Numerical Methods, automata theory, calculus of probability. Books.

Tags: book-recommendation

I am asking you to recommend me good books to learn:
1) Numerical Methods 
2) Automata theory
3) Calculus of probability

Books should be for someone who wants to start learn these subjects but does not want the books at kindergarten.

Comment: which part of numerical method is your need? ODE?

Comment: I don't know exactly. Something for computer scientists.

Comment: not r reference but it is not bad: youtube.com/watch?v=Vs2usBZjUO8